# Setting default "View" in AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that by default does not show protected ranges.
The user needs to know which range is protected - he can do that by going to Menu->View-> Check "protected ranges".
[image]
Is it possible to set the "protected ranges" option to check by default?

Comment: However you could set Background to a different color on protected ranges, though not currently possible due to a [ongoing  issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148894990)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this time Google Apps Script does not have a method for achiving this. If you wish you could make a feature request for a method to perform this [HERE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Comment: However you could set Background to a different color on protected ranges, though not currently possible due to a [ongoing  issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148894990)